# Which css properties for cross browser opacity are recommend for usage today?

Tags: css, opacity

I was wondering what is recommended now a day for using opacity in css, that will work for most of broswers and versions.

Should that be only `opacity` and `filter` or should I use still '-ms-filter' too?

Thank you.

Comment: it seems you are confused. if you want to support older versions of IE, use `-ms` vendor prefix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
.transparent {
/* Required for IE 5, 6, 7 */
/* ...or something to trigger hasLayout, like zoom: 1; */
width: 100%; 

/* Theoretically for IE 8 & 9 (more valid) */   
/* ...but not required as filter works too */
/* should come BEFORE filter */
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

/* This works in IE 8 & 9 too */
/* ... but also 5, 6, 7 */
filter: alpha(opacity=50);

/* Older than Firefox 0.9 */
-moz-opacity:0.5;

/* Safari 1.x (pre WebKit!) */
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;

/* Modern!
/* Firefox 0.9+, Safari 2?, Chrome any?
/* Opera 9+, IE 9+ */
opacity: 0.5;
  }
```

For today usage.

```
.transparent {
zoom: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
opacity: 0.5;
}
```

[source](http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/)

Answer (score 0):

For setting opacity, it's generally best to use `rgba(red, green, blue, alpha)` (with `color`, `background`, or any other property that uses a color value); the `opacity` property affects all descendants (you can only make things more transparent with `opacity`, it's not possible to make things more opaque than their ancestor), whereas with rgba(), the alpha value isn't cumulative, so you don't end up getting stuck in a situation where you suddenly need to change the DOM structure to undo transparency on some element.